# Browser Back Button Redirect Script

Tags: javascript, redirect, button, browser, back

I am trying to develop the Browser Back Button redirect script.

So basically when the user arrives at index.html for google or any other social media, on clicking the back button the user should go to the specified page.

I tried creating it with javascript, But it's not working. Anybody can help about it?

**I created 3 pages**

**1) Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p><a href="redirect.html">Redirect Page</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

**2)redirect.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function init() {
setTimeout(function(){window.scrollTo(0,1)},0);
}

window.history.pushState(‘back.html’, ‘back’, ‘back.html’);
window.history.pushState(‘index.html’, ‘Index’, ‘index.html’);
window.addEventListener(“popstate”, function(e) {
if(document.URL.indexOf(“back.html”) >= 0){
document.location.href = document.location;
}

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<p>By pressing the browser back button it should redirect to specified url</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**3) back.html**

```
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>
<head>
<script>

document.location.href = “https://www.google.com”;

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```